# How display only years in input Bootstrap Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using the following code to display only the years:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {viewMode: "years", minViewMode: "years"});
```

but input appears in the format `"dd/mm/yyyy"`

How can I solve this since I do not have the format `"yyyy"`?

Comment: Answered prominently in [the docs](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)...

Comment: Sara I saw the documentation but it does not accept the option format = "yyyy".

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try this

```js
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```

Comment: that's exactly the same I've used in the example

Comment: I was using format: "yyyy" instead of format: " yyyy". Thank you for your help.

Comment: @ZoltanToth: How to remove extra space?

Comment: prev button on claender not working in that case. any suggestion

Comment: How about to add range years? @ZoltanToth

Answer (score 11):

For `bootstrap datetimepicker`, assign `decade` value as follow:

```
$(".years").datetimepicker({
    format: "yyyy",
    startView: 'decade',
    minView: 'decade',
    viewSelect: 'decade',
    autoclose: true,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#year").datepicker( {
    format: "yyyy",
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
}).on('changeDate', function(e){
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For bootstrap 3 datepicker. (Note the capital letters)

```
$("#datetimepicker").datetimepicker( {
  format: "YYYY",
  viewMode: "years"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

always year for bootstrap 3 datetimepicker 
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

```
   $('#year').datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY',
        viewMode: "years",
    });

    $("#year").on("dp.hide", function (e) {
        $('#year').datetimepicker('destroy');
        $('#year').datetimepicker({
            format: 'YYYY',
            viewMode: "years",
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
format: "YYYY"
```

Should be capital instead of "yyyy"