# Restrict selection on datepicker with viewMode set to years

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using the solution provided on [How display only years in input Bootstrap Datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128701/how-display-only-years-in-input-bootstrap-datepicker) to show only years on datepicker.

Live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rp1kz6yb/2/)

My datepicker has the following configuration:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```

I've tried to set `endDate: '0d'` and it didn't work.

How can I set an endDate which will prevent me from selecting a future year using that solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me by passing the endDate attribute as the current date object retrieved by the Date() default constructor.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: " yyyy", // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years",
    endDate: new Date()
});
```

By playing around with the JavaScript Date object, you should be able to set the max to be a date within any year you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( { minDate: -0, maxDate: new Date(2013, 1,18) });
```

Comment: Doesn't work on my configuration. I added my configuration to the post.